# SDL_Init crashes without apparent reason

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2

I'm trying to write a simple SDL2 and OpenGL program but `SDL_Init` causes my application to crash right at the beggining.
Here's the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

#define WIN_WIDTH 800
#define WIN_HEIGHT 600


int CALLBACK WinMain(
  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
  LPSTR lpCmdLine, 
  int nCmdShow) {

  int err;
  SDL_Window *window;
  SDL_GLContext context;
  uint32_t win_flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;

  std::cout << "before";

  if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    std::cout << "fail";
    std::cout << "SDL Init Error: " << SDL_GetError() << std::endl;
  }

  std::cout << "success";

  window = SDL_CreateWindow("rgb", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
    WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT, win_flags);

  context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(window);

  SDL_GL_DeleteContext(context);
  SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
  SDL_Quit();

  return 0;
}
```

And the output is:

```
before
```

Then it crashes.

Debugger output (when it enters WinMain):

```
WinMain (hInstance=0x0, hPrevInstance=0x1d04aa0, lpCmdLine=0x0, nCmdShow=0)
    at src/main.cpp:15
15    int nCmdShow) {
(gdb) s
20    uint32_t win_flags = SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL;
(gdb) s
22    std::cout << "before" << std::endl;
(gdb) s
before
24    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Comment: Add a `<< std::endl` to your outputs to make sure that you flush the output buffer. It's possible that you're just not seeing the output.

Comment: @molbdnilo still crashing.

Comment: I would expect that it's still crashing. Do you still get the same output? If you run in a debugger, where does it stop and what does it say?

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, and I edited the question and added the debugger output.

Comment: It looks like you're not debugging a debug build. Try using a debug build. It may also be time to build with the development libraries so you can find out where in `SDL_Init` it occurs.

Comment: @molbdnilo I did compile with the `-g` option now, but it didn't help much (or there is something else for debugging?). And are you meaning that I should build SDL from source?